# Multiple Serialize User in PassportJs using MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

Am developing application using Nodejs with MySQL..

For login Authentication am using passportJS.
There are two login in this application one for admin and another one for customer. so seperate tables is there are USERS and REGISTERS.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, {
     id      : user.id,
     isAdmin : user.isAdmin // or some other property/check
 });
});

    // used to deserialize the user


passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
var table = user.isAdmin ? 'register' : 'users';
connection.query('select * from ?? where id = ?', [ table, user.id ], function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    } else if (! Array.isArray(rows) || ! rows.length) {
        return done();
    } else {
        return done(null, rows[0]);
    }
});
```

});

In deserializeuser if i logging In with customer id...its checking with user table for same id...so am getting wrong data

Question Updated:
**Local-Login for Admin**

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

        connection.query("select * from users WHERE email = '" + email + "'",function(err,rows){
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
            } 
            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!( rows[0].password == password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, rows[0]);         

        });

    }));
```

**Customer-Login**

```
  passport.use('customer-login', new LocalStrategy({
       usernameField : 'mobile',
       passwordField : 'otp',
       passReqToCallback : true 
  },
function(req, mobile, otp, done) { 

connection.query("select * from register WHERE mobile = '" + mobile + "'",function(err,rows){
    if (err)
        return done(err);
    if (!rows.length) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
    } 
    // if the user is found but the password is wrong
    if (!( rows[0].otp == otp))
        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
    // all is well, return successful user
    console.log(rows);
    return done(null, rows[0]);         

});

}));
```

For admin am using email as username for login

For customer am using mobile number for login

**register**
[image: registertable]

**users**
[image: user table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to serialize *just* the user id in `serializeUser`, it can also be an object that contains (for instance) the admin status (from your database contents, it looks like `cust_code` only exists for regular users, so we can use that to check if a user is an admin or not):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, {
    id      : user.id,
    isAdmin : user.cust_code === undefined // this does require that `cust_code`
                                           // is defined for all regular users.
  });
});
```

This obviously assumes that the `user` document contains *something* that reflects if the user is an admin or not.

Using that object in `deserializeUser` you can determine which table to query:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  var table = user.isAdmin ? 'users' : 'register';
  connection.query('select * from ?? where id = ?', [ table, user.id ], function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    } else if (! Array.isArray(rows) || ! rows.length) {
      return done();
    } else {
      return done(null, rows[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: how to write condition if **isAdmin** to check on **users*** table else on register table

Comment: `var table = user.isAdmin ? 'users' : 'register'`

Comment: am getting this error **Error: failed to deserialize user out of session**

Comment: It _would_ invalidate existing sessions, so you need to clean your session storage before applying this code.

Comment: So check what `err` is.

Comment: eg: id=1, this id is exist in both users and register table..but the login details is from register table on that time it retrieve data from users table

Comment: Since the id exists in both tables, you need to know which table to query. That's what my answer is trying to provide: to query just one table.

Comment: pls see above ur answer.. i hav updated your answer...but still its not working

Comment: I edited your edit. If it doesn't work, can you provide details (in your question) why it doesn't work?

Comment: Your strategy setup isn't directly useful, other than that I would strongly advise you to use [query escaping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: see above i have updated my question with your answer..i hope u got a answer

Comment: how to identify who is logging in wheather Admin or User

Comment: @Nodemon I don't know, I don't know what you have stored in your database.

Comment: It looks like `cust_code` only exists for regular users, so `isAdmin : user.cust_code !== undefined` might work.